# or clause in equals, hash code

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I have a class with two members, a and b. The class and equals is implemented as following:

```
public static class Test {
    protected int a;
    protected int b;

    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        } else if (o instanceof Test) {
            final Test t = (Test) o;

            return a == t.a || b == t.b;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

How do I write an efficient hash code function?

Thanks.

Comment: You sure it ought to be `||`?

Comment: Looks like a design smell to me. What's your use case for such an equals method?

Comment: Why not generate one using Eclipse's "Generate HashCode() and Equals()"?

Comment: It is indeed OR clause, not AND.

Comment: You will have to ensure that you return the same *hashcode* for `Test(1,2)` and `Test(1,10).`

Comment: In any case, this `equals` method breaks the contract, because it is not transitive. It will say that `(1,2).equals((2,3))` and `(2,3).equals((3,4))`, but **not** that `(1,2).equals((3,4))`.

Comment: @TheLostMind, @Marco13 it should be `(1,2).equals(3,2)` and `(3,2).equals(3,4)`, but **not** `(1,2).equals(3,4)`. Transitivity is not given any more, so no worry about hash code... ;)

Comment: @TheLostMind Sure, that's what I meant (and what isnot2bad said). Can't edit any more, but the key problem remains (namely, it's not transitive any more)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the only `hashcode()` method that will satisfy the equals / hashcode contract with that implementation of `equals(Object)` is a method that returns a constant.

---

Like others, I don't understand why you would want to define an `equals` method with those semantics.  Among other things, you've defined equality to be non-transitive:

```
X.equals(Y) && Y.equals(Z) does not imply X.equals(Z)
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, hence my question. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Or more generally, a hashcode that uses neither `a` nor `b` but only variables that are required to be equal in the equals method.

Comment: @tobias_k - I don't think that generalization is possible.  It can't depends on any *other* variable either ...

Comment: @StephenC Maybe my comment was unclear; edited. I meant that it must only use values that are required to be equal. If there are other variables, that are not tested at all in equals, not even with `or`, they should not be part of `hashCode` either.

Comment: @tobias_k - Lets restrict this to the OP's actual example where equality depends on the two variables `a` and `b` ... only.

Comment: ...which hardly is efficient :-)

Comment: @laune - In one sense, you couldn't define a more efficient hash function than this :-)

Comment: Returning a constant in the `hashCode()` method still won't satisfy the current `equals()` method, as `hashCode()` shows that such objects are always equal even though `equals()` says otherwise.

Comment: @Unihedron `hashCode` never says something about equality. If two objects have the same hash code, they are not necessarily equal too! (But of course, the opposite is true).

Comment: @isnot2bad You are correct - The documentation says "_It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results._" Lack of experience for hashing myself.

Comment: @Unihedron It's easy to memorize: There are far more different `String` objects than possible `int` values, hence there must exist two non-equal `String` objects, that have the same `hashCode`.

Comment: @StephenC While your statement is true, the request, however, was for an "efficient" but not for "the most efficient" hash function. Which leaves us with the rather paradox situation that the most efficient hash function isn't an efficient one. (A truly marvellous piece of reasoning, if I may say so!)

Comment: @laune - The word you are looking for is "effective".

Answer (score 0):

If you want your own hashcode try this

```
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 7 * hash + a;
    hash = 7 * hash + b;
```

But I thing you should use [hashCodeBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) from Apache Utilis

BTW

```
return a == t.a || b == t.b;
```

are you sure?

Comment: With this equals you can't use the proposed function.